# Git branch name in ps-left-header

Tags: git, emacs, ps

I want to display the current Git branch I am on within the header when I print via postscrpt but cannot figure out how to do that.

It appears in the mode-line, from what appears to be (vc-mode vc-mode) but adding that to ps-left-header doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What mode line do you speak of? It sounds like you are talking about something within emacs.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to emacs.  I thought I was posting on an emacs specific board, sorry.

Comment: Using tags in your question such as `git` and `ps` will reach non-Emacs audiences, and thus people will downvote your question and/or vote to close your question.

Comment: The function `vc-mode-line` in the library `vc-hooks.el` looks interesting -- especially the part where `(setq vc-mode (concat ...` -- perhaps that can steer you in the right direction -- i.e., check that variable value and see if looks like what you may want.

Comment: You need to edit your question; people shouldn't need to read the tags and comments to understand that you are talking about emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got what you need, I think. If you put a symbol in the `ps-left-header` list, then that symbol gets funcalled. Although I couldn't find this in the documentation, it seems that it gets called with the buffer that you're printing as the current buffer.

Now, the variable `vc-mode` is a buffer-local variable that gets set to something useful by the code that deals with the mode line. In fact, it generally looks something like " Git-master" (with the leading space) so you'll probably want to transform it somewhat. Also, it comes with lots of text properties we don't need. Suppose that you've written a more useful version of this:

```
(defun vc-mode-as-string () (substring-no-properties vc-mode))
```

Then I think you can just add the symbol `vc-mode-as-string` to `ps-left-header` to get what you want. Maybe `vc-mode-as-string` should also check that `vc-mode` is a string and return `""` otherwise. (I've just checked and the variable is always bound, but is `nil` when there's no version control)

To do a "quick and dirty" check when writing this, I used the following in IELM:

```
ELISP> (let ((ps-left-header (cons 'vc-mode-as-string ps-left-header)))
         (with-current-buffer "app.cc"
           (ps-spool-buffer-with-faces)))
"Formatting...done"
```

("app.cc" is a buffer that is under version control on my Emacs at the moment).

Hopefully these hints should be enough for you to build what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Rupert, I added the following to my .emacs file and I now have the git info in my Postscript header:`;Append the Git branchname to the postscript header
    (defun vc-mode-as-string () (substring-no-properties vc-mode))
    (setq ps-left-header (append ps-left-header '(vc-mode-as-string)))`

Comment: I had to change `(defun vc-mode-as-string () (if vc-mode (substring-no-properties vc-mode) " "))`